# Run SQL Server job steps in parallel

Tags: sql-server, sql-job

I have a SQL Server job that runs 6 steps, each executes the same exe command but with different parameters.

My question: is it possible to execute these steps all in parallel and not sequentially, without splitting the job into 6 jobs?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an SSIS package or you can put all 6 jobs, then you create an SQL job that executes the package.

if it suits you, mark the answer as a solution.